# There exist unique $x, y\in \Bbb{N}$ that satisfy $x^2+84x + 2008=y^2$. Find $x+y$.

Tags: number-theory, quadratics

> There exist unique $x, y\in \Bbb{N}$ that satisfy $x^2+84x + 2008=y^2$. Find $x+y$.

I tried this question by completing the square on the left side, but the answer is coming out weird. Please help me.

Comment: when is the difference between squares even ?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint :Complete the square for $x$
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x+42)^2+244=y^2 \\
\color{red}{(y+x+42)}\color{blue}{(y-x-42)} = \color{red}{122} \times \color{blue}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

> $y=62,x=18$

Comment: How did you know you have to factor 244 like $122*2$ and not $61*4$ or something else?

Comment: @johnnobody It is only a hint ... the possiblitities of factoring $244$ as $ 1 \times 244 $ and $ 4 \times 61$ need to be explored and eliminated.

Comment: Ah, ok then, I thought there is something I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

The equation over the integers is
$$
x^2+84x+2008-y^2=0,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
x=\pm \sqrt{y^2-244}-42.
$$
Hence $y^2-244=z^2$ for some integer $z$, i.e., $(y-z)(y+z)=244$ For $244=2\cdot 122$ we obtain $y-z=2$ and $y+z=122$, so that
$y=62$, and $x=18$.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a little less bashing (and I think quicker solution):

We have:

$$ (x+42)^2 <x^2+84x+2008 <(x+45)^2$$
thus
$$ (x+42)^2 <y^2 <(x+45)^2$$
so 
$$ x+42 <y <x+45$$

so $y= x+43$ or $y=x+44$. Plugging in to original equation we get a solution.

Comment: You mean $x^2+84x+2008$ in the first line, right? But if you expand, you can easily see that the first inequality only holds for $2x<159$.

Comment: Ah, I wonted to write x+42, I messed all. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I was just about to comment that it's still quick enough, $y = x+43$ can be discarded since $x$ and $y$ must be of the same parity.

Comment: Can someone send me a detailed solution

Comment: @AtharvaShetty I have a detailed one...